# Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer warning

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, compiler-warnings

I've enabled ARC, In my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, I wrote the following code:

AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ViewController * vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    self.viewController = nav;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But the statement: `self.viewController = nav;` gets a compile warning, the warning info is:

`file://.../AppDelegate.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer types passing 'UINavigationController *__strong' to parameter of type 'ViewController *'`

[image: Compile Warning Information]

How to remove the warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that ViewController is a custom subclass of UIViewController which is either completely different *or* a subclass of UINavigationController itself. That's why it's wrong: a superclass can't completely act as it's subclass(es) (e. g., it may not have certain properties/methods etc.), hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you: "nav, an instance of a UINavigationController, is NOT a 'ViewController' or subclass of 'ViewController'". If you really want to hold on to both the Navigation Controller and your View Controller, you can add a second property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navController;
```

And then set it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
self.viewController = vc;
self.navController = nav;
```

*Another* solution here would be to just hold onto the Navigation Controller and use the 'topViewController' property to access your VC.

Edit: Or better yet, not care about the Navigation Controller. Simply do:

```
self.viewController = vc;
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
 self.viewController =[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

then it won't shows the warning of like"Incompatible pointer types passing 'UINavigationController *__strong' to parameter of type 'ViewController *"